# Showing that $x^2+\frac{1}{4} > x$ on $(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I don't recall having ever done a proof like this analytically, so I would appreciate your advice. Here's what I did, and it seems to be a correct approach, but there could be a better one.

Let $x:=\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon$ $\\$   (for $0<\varepsilon <1$). Now $f(x)=x^2+\frac{1}{4}=(\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon)^2+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2>\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon=x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your proof is fine.

---

For a different one, notice that

$$x^2 - x + \frac 1 4 = \left(x - \frac 1 2\right)^2 \ge 0$$
and equality is obtained if and only if $x = 1/2$, which is not in the domain.

---

For a still different proof, notice that the left hand side is twice the arithmetic mean of $x^2$ and $1/4$. The right side is twice the geometric mean (at least when $x \ge 0$). When $ x < 0$, the inequality is obvious.

Comment: Welcome back. $\,$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

hint:
$$\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=x^2-x+\frac{1}{4}$$